# React Native Integration Tests Always Passing (even when they shouldn't)

Tags: javascript, objective-c, xcode, integration-testing, react-native

I've been trying to get up and running with React Native Integration Tests, but have hit a bit of a stumbling block. When I run my integration tests in Xcode, they always pass, even if I edit them so that they should definitely fail.

I'm using the React Native module RCTTest to create a runner for the tests, exactly as they do in their example: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer/UIExplorerIntegrationTests, and using NativeModules.TestModule in the actual test files.

Running the example tests, everything works as expected, and I've even added my test to their runner, which then passes/ fails as it should, so I'm pretty sure my tests themselves are not the issue. I've also added an Objective-C test to run alongside the RN tests, and that also works as expected. I've added some console logs to the javascript test files, so I know the tests are actually being run.

I'm running Xcode 7 beta, but I've also had the same results in 6.4.

The full code I'm trying to get working is here: https://github.com/Danwhy/learn-react-native/tree/master/testing/testingTests

Anyone experienced a problem like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this problem by upgrading React Native to version 0.10.0.